# how get the exact public path where a rails app lives

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Lets assume my RoR app lives at

> http://case-1.example.com/part-1/sub-part-1/

In a view file, how can I get that path?

Answer (score 5):

To get full url of the current page you can use

```
current_url =  request.request_uri
```

This will return you full url, you can then gsub http or https.
Hope this was you were looking for.

Thanks..

Comment: @Sathish: Could you please accept the answer as a solution if this is what you was looking for and does resolves the issue. Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

For **rails 3+**
Use :

```
@app_root_path = Rails.root
```

For **rails < 3**
Use

```
@app_root_path = RAILS_ROOT
```

Comment: @ Pravin, I do not want something like: /Users/username/office/work/sub-part-1/.

But I want something like: http://case-1.example.com/part-1/sub-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path by following:-

```
@rails_app_path = RAILS_ROOT
```

Thanks......

Comment: @ Anubhaw, I do not want something like: /Users/username/office/work/sub-part-1/. But I want something like: case-1.example.com/part-1/sub-part-1. I want the path to the server not the local directory path.